# Can't retrieve identity and labels after collect + unwind in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a pretty complex query which involves some unwinds and collects, and mixes together different types of nodes. At the end of it, I'm left with a list of maps.
When I just return the list, I see that each element has the attributes `identity`, `labels`, and `properties`.

However, I don't seem to be able to retrieve the value of `identity` and `labels` through the key, `map_element.identity`, nor with `map_element["identity"]`.
I've tried using the functions `ID` and `labels` but it gives me the error that the element is a map and not a node.

Basic query to test on any data to see what I mean:

```
MATCH (a), (b)
WITH collect(a) + collect(b) as collected
UNWIND collected as unwinded
RETURN unwinded, unwinded.identity
```

You will notice that in the `unwinded` column, `identity`, `labels`, and `properties` are present, however `unwinded.identity` is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `id(unwinded)` and `labels(unwinded)` ?

Answer (score 0):

ID function is the equivalence of getting that identity property:

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id

For labels, it is the same labels function:
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-labels

```
MATCH (a), (b)
WITH collect(a) + collect(b) as collected
UNWIND collected as unwinded
RETURN unwinded, ID(unwinded), unwinded.<property>
```